# Trying to understand lists in recursive ways step by step

Tags: prolog

```
concatenar([], Xs, Xs).
concatenar([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]) :- concatenar(Xs,Ys,Zs).

?- concatenar([a, d, c], [s, a, d], Z).
Z = [a, d, c, s, a, d]

?- concatenar(T, [s, a, d], [a, d, c, s, a, d]).
T = [s, a, d]
```

---

```
% Mínimo elemento de una lista
%Ejemplo: minimo([1,5,3,-2],X). X=-2

minimo([X], X).
minimo([X|Xs], X) :- minimo(Xs,Y), X =< Y.
minimo([X|Xs], N) :- minimo(Xs,N), N < X.
```

Comment: `concatenar([], Xs, Xs).` means that if you concatenate `[]` and `Xs` you get `Xs`. `concatenar([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) :- concatenar(Xs, Ys, Zs)` says that `[X|Zs]` is the result of concatenating `[X|Ys]` and `Ys` *if* `Zs` is the result of concatenating `Xs` and `Ys`. Follow the same kind of logic in understanding `minimo`. Think of the predicate clauses as rules.

Comment: You should write your questions in English. At any rate, recursion through lists is not very complicated. You can only remove elements from the front and you have no idea how many elements are in the list in total, so removing 1 is the safest. That way you can split a list in `functor([FirstElement|TheRest],_) :- not(some_check(FirstElement)), functor(TheRest).` and if an element does match your check you can return it `functor([FirstElement|_],FirstElement)`. Please write out your question English and specify what you want to know exactly, or just read Learn Prolog Now! online.

Comment: thank you to respond and sorry, I forgot to translate in English. I was watching some videos and reading but I don't find somebody that explain an example step by step recursivity with lists. I want to know step by step how recursivity is happening with an axample. for example with it

Comment: concatenate([ ], Xs, Xs).
concatenate([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]) :- concatenate(Xs,Ys,Zs).

?- concatenate([a, b, c], [s, a, d], Z).
Z = [a, b, c, s, a, d]

Comment: step 1: Xs have inside [b,c] and X [a]                                                  step2:    Xs have inside [c] and X [a,b]                                                                                             
 step 3: Xs have inside [ ] and X [a,b,c]     ys have inside [d,e,f]                                              step4: and then what happend?             I don't understand how [s,a,d] go inside X to have finally Z=[a,b,c,s,a,d]

Comment: You shouldn't elaborate in comments. If you want  to add more clarity to your question, please edit your question. Also, did you try using `trace` to watch execution? Use `trace` on a simple example, like `concatenar([a,b], [c,d], L).` Per one of your comments about step 1, initially, yes `Xs = [b, c]` in your example, but `X = a`, not `X = [a]` since the list is `[a,b,c]` which could be written, `[a | [b,c]]`. Your step 2 is incorrect. In Step 2, `X = b` and `Xs = [c]` since you are calling `concatenar([b,c], [s, a, d], Zs)`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I can't edit my post because have problems in add text, I have no idea. I am new using it.      thank you lurker!! and what happened in step 4, 5 and 6? because these steps I don't know how is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll help you through your first example. This should give you enough information to tackle the second on your own...

Here's your predicate:

```
concatenar([], Xs, Xs).
concatenar([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) :- concatenar(Xs,  Ys, Zs).
```

Now consider the query:

```
?- concatenar([a,b,c], [x,y,z], L).
```

Prolog will start at the beginning of your "database" (asserted facts and predicates) trying to unify the query term with the facts and predicate heads. The first attempt is with `concatenar([], Xs, Xs)`. Prolog is unable to unify the query term with this rule because `[]` does not unify with `[a,b,c]`. So Prolog moves on to the next predicate head, `concatenar([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) ...`. Here it can unify `[a,b,c] = [X|Xs]` via `X = a` and `Xs = [b,c]`, it can unify `[x,y,z] = Ys` as is, and it unifies `L = [X|Zs]` as is. Since it matched the head of this predicate clause through unification, Prolog will proceed with the body of the clause and call `concatenar(Xs, Ys, Zs)` which, through the unification of the  head, is `concatenar([b,c], [x,y,z], Zs)`.

Now you repeat the process over again. You have a new query, `concatenar([b,c], [x,y,z], Zs)` which attempts to unify with the first head, `concatenar([], Xs, Xs)`. No match, since `[b,c]` does not unify with `[]`. As before, Prolog moves on to the next clause and unifies `concatenar([b,c], [x,y,z], Zs)` with `concatenar([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs])` via `X = b`, `Xs = [c]`, `Ys = [x,y,z]`, and `Zs = [X|Zs']` (note, I used `Zs'` to distinguish the fact that this is a different variable than the other `Zs`). Again, as before, Prolog will proceed with the body of the clause and call `concatenar([c], [x,y,z], Zs')`.

If you continue this process to the next step, you'll finally match `concatenar([], Xs, Xs)` with `concatenar([], [x,y,z], [x,y,z])`. Then you have to unwind the recursion...

How did we get to the call to `concatenar([], [x,y,z], Zs)`? It came from a call to `concatenar([c|[]], [x,y,z], [c|Zs]) :- concatenar([], [x,y,z], Zs).` So when this call comes back, it results in `concatenar([c|[]], [x,y,z], [c|[x,y,z]])` or `concatenar([c], [x,y,z], [c,x,y,z])`.

And how did we get to that call? It came from a call to `concatenar([b|[c]], [x,y,z], [b|Zs]) :- concatenar([c], [x,y,z], Zs)`. So this one results in `concatenar([b|[c]], [x,y,z], [b|[c,x,y,z]])` or `concatenar([b,c], [x,y,z], [b,c,x,y,z])`.

And this call came from `concatenar([a|[b,c]], [x,y,z], [a|Zs]) :- concatenar([b,c], [x,y,z], Zs).` which results in `concatenar([a|[b,c]], [x,y,z], [a|[b,c,x,y,z]])` or `concatenar([a,b,c], [x,y,z], [a,b,c,x,y,z])`.

Tada! It's done.

Comment: Thank you so much!! you saved my life!!  so L is taking a letter since recursivity is running. is like a collecion or a lis L adding elements by steps of recursivity. L=[a], L[a,b], L[a,b,c], L[a,b,c,x,y,z]. I got it? thank you so much!! you made my day!

Comment: the last question. when you have concatenar([ ], [x,y,z], Zs') it match with concatenar([], Xs, Xs)? or how you get x,y,z to both sides?

Comment: I think that I got it. so the answer is [] unifies with [];  [x,y,z] unifies with Xs; Zs unifies with Xs; so Xs was unified before with [x,y,z] , Zs have now the same value. it is ok?

Comment: @LucianoFndz that is correct. When `concatenar([], [x,y,z], Zs)` unifies with `concatenar([], Xs, Xs)` you get `[] = []`, `[x,y,z] = Xs` and `Zs = Xs`. So `Zs = [x,y,z]`.

Comment: @LucianoFndz to answer your first question, the final list is filled in on the returns from the recursive calls. So you really get `L` of `[x,y,z]`, then `[c,x,y,z]`, then `[b,c,x,y,z]`, and finally `[a,b,c,x,y,z]`.

Comment: why in that way? because is using backtracking method so is adding back to front?

Comment: @LucianoFndz it's that way because if you follow the logic carefully as I described, it goes all the way down to the base case `concatenar([], [x,y,z], Zs)`, then the call to the base case has the next element, in this case, `c`. I can add more to my answer to explain...

Comment: @LucianoFndz now that I've gone through the whole process, you should try this at the Prolog prompt, but enter `trace.` first. Then enter `concatenar([a,b,c], [x,y,z], L).`  and press Space bar at each `?`.

Comment: thank you very much!!!!!! I understand now! is like a pyramid!!. first is taking a, then b then c, and then take the case base and take xyz and then is taking cxyz, then b,c,x,y,z and finally a,b,c,x,y,z